How can I make an infinite-scrolling marquee? I can't get my items to repeat
I'm sorry if this question is a bit elementary but I've been hitting into a wall with CSS for a bit now. And I can't wrap my head around infinite scrolling marquees. I still feel pretty confident/happy because I was able to figure out how to do the rest of the styling and sort of business on my own on the spot, but I just had a problem with making the .marquee-row-items repeat once they left the parent element.
I know I can just add more marquee row items but I only have a limited number to work with and I really wanna make this infinite scrolling without any large or noticeable gaps between animation. But in my code it always "restarts" rather than continuing if that makes sense.
Hopefully the code snippet is easier to understand.
I believe this can all be accomplished with CSS without touching JS... right?
I tried playing around with the width of the parent element and the row. I also looked up a tutorial that said to add a variable gap but even after playing with the code pen I don't think I understood it yet. I added the --gap variable.

HTML, CSS code:



.marquee {
  --gap: 1em;
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: center; */
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: var(--gap);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /*/ Allows psuedo-elements to position themselves relative to the container /*/
}

.marquee::before,
.marquee::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  /*/ Allows us to pause the animation by hover by removing div 'obstruction' /*/
}

.marquee::before {
  /*/ Adds a fade out/in effect at the both ends of our marquee container /*/
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent);
}

.marquee::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, black, transparent);
}

.marquee__row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  gap: var(--gap);
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* min-width: 100%; */
  animation: marqueeMoveX 10s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: marqueeMoveX 10s linear infinite;
}

.marquee__row:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.marquee__row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  animation-play-state: reverse;
}

.marquee__row__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.marquee__row__item i {
  font-size: 5em;
}

@keyframes marqueeMoveX {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap)));
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap)));
    -moz-transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap)));
    -ms-transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap)));
    -o-transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap)));
  }
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="marquee">
  <div class="marquee__row">
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fas fa-code"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fab fa-html5"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fab fa-js"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fas fa-microchip"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marquee__row">
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fab fa-java"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fab fa-php"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fab fa-sass"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fab fa-react"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee__row__item">
      <i class="fas fa-bug"></i> <span> code </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




read this: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation

Here is an example of an infinite adaptive running line. No js. However, pay attention to the comments in the code:

It is possible that the length of your line is less than the width of the screen, so you need to duplicate the text.

You need to know the exact length of your line in pixels, after loading the font and rendering. This can be calculated in js. Or calculated in advance and written into the code. Unfortunately, it happens that fonts are rendered differently in different browsers, so you will need to test your code in each browser separately.
CodePen Link




body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.running-line-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.running-line {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #444;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.running-line {
  animation: run 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes run {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  /* Magic is here. This is the width of the elem with text after rendering the page */
  to {
    transform: translateX(-1683.35px);
  }
}
<div class="running-line-wrapper">
  <div class="running-line">
    <!-- The overall width of the text element should be twice the width of the screen -->
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet *</span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet *</span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet *</span>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you for your help, I wasn't able to use the code necessarily the way it was written but it did help me realize my problem in the end was just because I didn't have enough meat to put on the table. And calucating by hand or in advance the width of the parent made me realize I'd just be better off duplicating my HTML until there was so much that the animation couldn't ever run off with a large gap.

@meAndTheBirds I would recommend not to duplicate the code when loading the page as already written html, but to duplicate it using js some time after the loading is finished. Or wrap the duplicated content in  tags. This is necessary so that search robots do not react to the fact that the content on the site is duplicated. Good luck!

OK, I feel silly but in the end it was just because I didn't have enough HTML elements to sell the illusion of an infinite marquee. I did want to try to accomplish a '.marquee__row' with only six '.marquee__row_item' elements per row but it just wasn't working. Even when I tried the solutions Andrei and Foysal have been so kind to provide.
My case just had too small of a width elements (and too large of a width page) for it to work. So I duplicated the number of elements I had on the screen and wrapped it up, I made sure to give the duplicate row (I had to make two more) aria-hidden='true' too.
I don't believe anything much more changed about my code except for the fact that I had to use...
.marquee:hover .marquee__row {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

To pause the animation state on children elements by simply hovering over the parent. If I hadn't then the children would be running themselves over.

In your code, you can set style in "marquee__row__item" class to set space. also if you want to change the speed just change time of animation "animation: marquee 25s linear infinite;" and it will pause on hover. Below is an example according to your code you can check.
<div class="marquee-container">
        <div class="marquee">
            <div class="marquee__row__item">
                <i class="fas fa-code"></i> <span>Sets how the text is scrolled within the marquee</span>
            </div>
            <div class="marquee__row__item">
                <i class="fab fa-html5"></i> <span>Sets the interval between each scroll movement in milliseconds</span>
            </div>
            <div class="marquee__row__item">
                <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i> <span>Fires when the marquee has reached the end of its scroll position. </span>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="marquee-container">
        <div class="marquee">
            <div class="marquee__row__item">
                <i class="fab fa-js"></i> <span>The key to controlling the speed is the animation-duration property in seconds</span>
            </div>
            <div class="marquee__row__item">
                <i class="fas fa-microchip"></i> <span>When the user hovers over .marquee-container, the animation-play-state is set to paused, stopping the animation temporarily.</span>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
<style type="text/css">
        .marquee-container {
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .marquee {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-left: 100%; /* Start off screen */
            animation: marquee 25s linear infinite;
        }

        .marquee .marquee__row__item {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 50px; /* Gap between items */
        }

        @keyframes marquee {
            from {
                transform: translateX(0%);
            }
            to {
                transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }

        .marquee-container:hover .marquee {
            animation-play-state: paused; /* Stop scrolling on hover */
        }
    </style>


Thank you for your help, especially that last selector you used I didn't know about it before. I ended up resorting to duplicating my HTML because I just didn't have a lot of content to expand my width. I was dealing with font awesome icons rather than sentences so I don't think it would've been a pleasant experience either for me or for the end-result.
